# Distance Vector Routing Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, router

Can anyone explain the Distance Vector Routing Algorithm from basics ?
I have been searching for material all over the internet from past few hours , but at no place is it explained in a way such that beginners can understand . Either it is explained with very small examples (trying to apply the algorithm to a different example seems very difficult) or it is explained very vaguely .
If possible , please explain with a 'good' example .

PS : I have a really big problem in understanding EXACTLY WHEN and IN WHICH ORDER do the routers exchange the information . I have to implement a C or C++ program for this algorithm . So I am trying to understand it completely .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you checked this:- http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa10/cse123/lectures/123-fa10-l13.pdf

Comment: Yes , that document explains it well , but not 'very clearly' . I read it more than 3 times . Still many things are missing .

Comment: Could you please tell what all things it is missing? I mean what you are trying to understand?

Comment: @Rahul , In the link you gave , it is not mentioned how are the costs for direct links of a node stored ? OK . Let me assume they are stored in a two dimensional array . What about DV's . What exactly is a DV ? And in the example provided in your link , it is very unclear what are costs and what are DV's ? And any beginner would understand a step-by-step working out of the example with exact labeling of the steps . All that is missing . And also , it is not given clearly , how does the exchange of values takes place ? I mean referring to a timeline and what all information a particular node ..

Comment: .. has access to at that time . Loots of lots of stuff is not clear . I mean for a person who already knows the algorithm (explained by a good teacher) , those might be obvious . But for someone trying to understand it from the basics , definitely not . Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Start with distance-vector:
    0 for self,
    D for neighbor at distance D.

Every 30 seconds,
    For each neighbor,
        Send the current distance vector, with entries that pass trough
            that neighbor set to 16.

When receiving a distance-vector from a neighbor,
    Save the received distance vector.
    If any estimated distance, trough this neighbor, has changed,
        Update the current vector, but cap at 16.

When 180 seconds has passed since the last message from some neighbor,
    Set it's distance to 16.
    Send the updated distance vector as above.
```

180 seconds is the standard time-out value. A distance of 16 is considered to be infinity.

Since the node does not immediately know every other node in the network, it can't add all the columns immediately. Easiest would be to use a table:

```
(Neighbor, Destination, Distance)
```

The current vector would be the minimum distance for each destination, plus one.

The pseudo-code above implements *Split Horizon* and *Poisoned Reverse*, but not *Triggered Updates*

---

**Read more:**

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2453.txt